# Linear Algebra : find the kernel of this transformation.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification

Q. I think I find the kernel but several... which is correct? Seems like depending on which variable I put as kernel, I can get several kernels. Correct?

T is the transformation from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$ whose matrix is A
$$A = \left(\begin{array}{cc}
\frac{1}{4}&\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}\\\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}&\frac{3}{4}\\\end{array}\right)$$

I need to find the kernel of T. And the following is my solution.
$$\left(\begin{array}{cc}
\frac{1}{4}&\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}\\\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}&\frac{3}{4}\\\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{cc}
x_{1}\\x_{2}\\\end{array}\right) = \vec{O}$$

So I have

$$\left(\begin{array}{cc}
\frac{1}{4}&\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}\\\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}&\frac{3}{4}
\end{array}\;\middle\vert\;\begin{array}{cc}\\0\\0\end{array}\right) ---rref---  \left(\begin{array}{cc}
1&\sqrt{3}\\0&0
\end{array}\;\middle\vert\;\begin{array}{cc}\\0\\0\end{array}\right)$$

Then I get the following equation in which I get really confused.

$$ x_{1} + \sqrt{3}x_{2} = 0 $$

Which variable should I put t as a free variable?

1st cast: $$ \left(\begin{array}{cc}
x_{1}\\x_{2}\\\end{array}\right) = \left(\begin{array}{cc}
t\\-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}t\\\end{array}\right) = \left(\begin{array}{cc}
1\\-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\\\end{array}\right)t ---> ker(T) = span\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1\\-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\\\end{array}\right) $$

2nd cast: $$ \left(\begin{array}{cc}
x_{1}\\x_{2}\\\end{array}\right) = \left(\begin{array}{cc}
-\sqrt{3}t\\t\\\end{array}\right) = \left(\begin{array}{cc}
-\sqrt{3}\\1\\\end{array}\right)t ---> ker(T) = span\left(\begin{array}{cc}
-\sqrt{3}\\1\\\end{array}\right) $$

Which is correct?
I am so confused.

Help me.
Thanks,

Comment: Oh in the middle, I did row-reduced echelon form to get it

Comment: $x_1=1,x_2=-\sqrt{3}$ is not a solution for $x_1+\sqrt{3}x_2=0$

Comment: I just corrected it. THanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$x_1+\sqrt{3}x_2=0\rightarrow x_1=-\sqrt{3}x_2\rightarrow (x_1,x_2)=(-\sqrt{3}x_2,x_2)=(-\sqrt{3},1)x_2\rightarrow \ker(T)=span(-\sqrt{3},1)$

Comment: How about this ? $$ ker(T) = span\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1\\-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\\\end{array}\right) $$

Comment: Do I have two kernels?

Comment: @user2310042 it is the same , the two vectors $(-\sqrt{3},1)$ and $(1,-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}})$ differ by the constant $-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$ hence generate the same subspace

Answer (score 0):

The first cast can't be correct. define $A$ the martrix of the linear transformation, and v the row vector $(1; -\sqrt{3})$. It is easy calculate that $Av^t \neq 0$ (in fact it is $(-\frac{1}{2},\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})$.

In fact you made a mistake calculate the first solution, if $x=t$ then $\sqrt{3}y=-t$ then $y=-\frac{t}{\sqrt{3}}$

Comment: I just corrected but I still seem to get two kernels... Thanks

Comment: you obtain two different representations of the same kernel. the first cast is span$(1,-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}})$ (i call "v" this vector) wich is equal to the second because $-\sqrt{3}*v=(-\sqrt{3},1)$ so the two spans are the same

Comment: remember the definition of span(v) and you will be ok :)